# Cannot populate data in lightning data table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, datatable

```
<aura:component controller="DisplayconsClass">
    <aura:attribute type="Contact[]" name="consList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>     
         <lightning:datatable  keyField="id" data="{!v.consList}" columns="{!v.mycolumns}" hideCheckboxColumn="true" />

</aura:component>
```

//controller

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.fetchContacts(component, event, helper);
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    fetchContacts: function(component, event)

    {

        component.set('v.mycolumns', [{
                label: 'First Name',
                fieldName: 'firstName',
                type: 'text'
            },
            {
                label: 'Last Name',
                fieldName: 'lastname',
                type: 'text'
            }

        ]);


        var action = component.get("c.fetchCons");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

            var state = response.getState();

            if (state === "SUCCESS") {

                var records = response.getReturnValue();

                component.set("v.consList", records);

            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Output:

[image]

Apex controller:

```
public class DisplayconsClass {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List <contact> fetchCons() {

        return [ SELECT firstName, lastname FROM contact LIMIT 10 ];

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Nishanth - can you please add the Apex controller code as well?  Also, it would be helpful to make the code more readable (less spacing and less newlines)

Comment: @BrianMiller: Added the apex controller.

Answer (score 3):

Field names are cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. It should be `FirstName` and `LastName`, not `firstName` and `lastname`. You must use the case from their API name, not however you've written it in your Apex code query.

---

```
    component.set('v.mycolumns', [{
            label: 'First Name',
            fieldName: 'FirstName',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            label: 'Last Name',
            fieldName: 'LastName',
            type: 'text'
        }

    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the apex controller to the following:

   public class DisplayconsClass {

   @AuraEnabled
       public static List  fetchCons() {
            List listToReturn = new List();
            List tempList = SELECT firstName, lastname FROM contact LIMIT 10 ];

   ```
        for(Contact temp : tempList){
           CotactWrapper tempWrap = new ContactWrapper();
           tempWrap.firstName = temp.firstName;
           tempWrap.lastname = temp.lastname;
           listToReturn.add(tempWrap);
        }
        return ListToReturn;
   }

   public class ContactWrapper{
       @AuraEnabled public String firstName;
       @AuraEnabled public String lastname;
   }
   ```

   }
2. In your JavaScript controller change to the following code:

   ```
   if (state === "SUCCESS") {
          var records = response.getReturnValue();
          var toJson = JSON.stringify(records);
          component.set("v.consList", toJson);

   }
   ```

Tbh I'm not sure whether it's JSON.stringify or JSON.parse so just try both.

3. in the component change the attribute:

> ```
> <aura:attribute type="Object" name="consList"/>
> ```

or Object[]

Comment: You wouldn't use JSON.stringify or JSON.parse. The return value is already a list of objects.

Comment: @sfdcfox I think you have to. That the way to match between the fieldName of the column to the attribute of the wrapper class, no?

Comment: The Aura framework takes care of converting your wrapper to native objects in JavaScript automatically. The only reason you'd need JSON.parse is if you returned a JSON string originally.

Comment: @sfdcfox Got your point, the problem was about case-sensitive. Thanks for your input.

Comment: It was the case sensitive issue and thank you @sfdcfox